# npm WARN config global `--global`,`--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I am getting below error while I am trying to install npm modules using
npm install

I already have npm and node.js installed.

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\test/package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\test\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-10-20T11_34_43_246Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Which module you are trying to install?

Comment: typeorm and also the modules which are mentioned in package.json